# Assume that $X,X_1,X_2,...$ are iid with characteristic function $\phi(t)=\mathbb E[e^{itx}]$, and let $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + ...$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume that $X,X_1,X_2,...$ are iid with characteristic function $\phi(t)=\mathbb E[e^{itx}]$, and let $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + ...$.

(a) For a random variable $X$, $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution iff $\phi$ is real.

Comment: I can show this by the inversion formula. I just plug in the formula; however, is there a simple way to see this rather than writing all the steps out?

(b) Express the characteristic function of the sample average, $\phi_{\frac{S_n}{n}}(t)$, in terms of $\phi$.

Comment: This one is easy. $\phi_{\frac{S_n}{n}}(t) = [\phi(\frac{t}{n})]^n$.

(c) Assume $\phi'(0)=0$. Show that $\frac{S_n}{n}$ converges to zero in probability.

I have no idea about this one.

For (d) and (e), we assume $X$ has density: $f(x)=c\frac{1}{x^2 ln|x|} \chi_{\{|x|>4\}}$, where $c$ is the appropriate normalizing constant.

(d) Show $\mathbb E{|X|}=\infty$

Commnet: Just plug in the definition formula of the expectation.

(e) Show that the ch.f for $X$ has $\phi'(0)=0$.

Like (c), I don't know how to show this one either.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how you arrived at the characteristic function of the sample average in part (b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

(a) $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution iff their characteristic functions are equal;

(c) Lévy theorem;

(e) $$1-\phi(t) = 2c\int_4^\infty \frac{(1-\cos tx)\, dx}{x^2\ln x} = 2ct \int_{4t}^\infty \frac{(1-\cos z)\, dz}{z^2(\ln z-\ln t)} = o(t),\ t\to 0.
$$
in view of the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: How did you express the first equality using integral? You used cos and sin to express the exponential funciton? Where is the sin funciton？

Comment: @hil316, the term with sine integrates to zero.